# GAE Datastore querying by index

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have created entities in the datastore. I want to use the index assigned to them by the datstore for queries.
i.e get an iterable back where the id is greater than a given number
e.g.

```
Query q = new Query("MyEntity");
q.addFilter("id",Query.FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, startId);
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
```

I know I can get back an individual entity back via id - but how to get a list ?

Cheers,

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Bear in mind that IDs are not assigned sequentially, so iterating over them in order isn't likely to be useful for anything much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Iterable<Entity> myEntities = pq.asIterable();
List<Entity> myEntitiesInAList = pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withChunkSize(500));
```

Side note:
"id" is not the name of the key assigned automatically by App Engine.  I think you must use `__key__` as the property name to do queries on it, and construct a full key as the search parameter, not just the long `id`.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to remember where you left off and continue there on a subsequent query, consider using a [query cursor](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html#Query_Cursors). The example on that page might give you some further options.